# Get device displacement with accelerometer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been working on a project where we need to capture the smartphone displacement to capture a movement like a shoulder elevation and identify if the movement is correct or wrong. Is this possible to do?

The movement is a flood of the arm, and I need to know the displacement to say if it is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is achievable. There is some scientific literature regarding this problem, which you may find useful, such as ["Arm Motion Recognition and Exercise Coaching System for Remote Interaction"](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/misy/2016/9849720/), ["What Can an Arm Holster Worn Smart Phone Do for Activity Recognition?"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5959598), and ["Motion recognition with smart phone embedded 3-axis accelerometer sensor"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6377845)